# How to select multiple categories(more than 20-30 unique values) in dropdown with ease?

Tags: html, user-interface, drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I am running an application where users can select categories for a selected field:
example: user-selected field = 'country' then the user can select 'country names'(India, China, America etc.) in the dropdown.

This works well when categories have unique values less than 15(this may vary). But when users need to select more than 15 categories it becomes very difficult for the user. I wanted to know what are the best possible solutions to ease this process?

example: user-selected field 'city' now users want to select 200 city names from the dropdown.

It can be a box where user can paste comma sepearated  category values and we can auto fill these in dropdowns, or a simple file upload.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: 1-30, 15-20...what? Please read [ask]. Create a [mcve]. Otherwise you're expecting load of subjective answers on a not so clear question. (And why creating a second profile?)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not make a dropdown but a input field and validate it via options list (like in dropdown but type-to-select) small example:

```
<input list="id"></input>
<datalist id="id">
<option value="USA"></option>
<option value="GERMANY"></option>
<option value="RUSSIA"></option>
<option value="CHINA"></option>
<option value="FRANCE"></option>
<option value="INDIA"></option>
<option value="UK"></option>
</datalist>
```

hope this helps =] if you dont know how it works - copy it to any html file to  tag and just use on custom page to understand =]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution will be to give the user a text box, where the user can paste comma-separated values and we can extract and auto-select the defined values.